# Launching WP7 Map Application

Tags: windows-phone-7, mapping, bing-maps

Hopefully this is an easy one.

In my app, I have an event page with an address listed. Currently I have a link to view map which brings up a page in my application that uses the map control, and using lat/long that I pass, displays the location of the event.

What I would like for it to do is to send the lat/long to the existing maps **application** so any driving directions (etc) could be handled by that application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two new Tasks introduced in the 'Mango' release of WindowsPhone. BingSearchTask & BingDirectionsTask are very useful for map functionality.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.bingmapsdirectionstask_members(v=VS.92).aspx

Refer this link for all the tasks available - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428753(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: Just a correction: The task are called `BingMapsTask` and `BingMapsDirectionsTask`. You can use `BingMapsTask.SearchTerm` to set the location to show.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't an existing Maps launcher (I really wish there was), the only work around at the moment that I've seen is a [Pseudo Map Launcher](http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/12/07/wp7-tip-pseudo-map-launcher/) by Kevin Marshall.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you mean the Phone's built-in map application, and that you'd like to launch that application with the desired coordinates?
As of the January update, that's still not possible, sorry.

But I work on the API for Windows Phone, so I'll be sure to keep your feedback in mind.

Comment: I'm glad this caught your attention, I'd love to incorporate such an API into my app too, if MS were to make it available.

Comment: it would be great if this was officially supported. I know a few folks over there. maybe i'll see if I can assert some additional influence :)